# Capture Raw Request with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Rather than using a proxy, trying to capture the raw HTTP request message via Puppeteer.

Here's a basic example of what I'm doing.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 800 })

  await page.setRequestInterception(true)

  page.on('request', (request) => {
    console.log(request) // <-- I want raw HTTP(S) message, not an object
    request.continue()
  })

  page.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log('<<', response.status(), response.url())
  })

  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')

  await browser.close()
})()
```

When I print out the request, I get the Node / JSON object that represents the request.

How do I get the raw request message?

Comment: What do you mean by raw request message? Do you need to look anything specific?

Comment: The raw HTTP message being sent to the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages

Comment: Do you mean by raw message, Request headers, and body, etc?

Comment: Yes, the raw request message

Answer (score 1):

@openwonk, hello!

You can use following ways to get raw data:

1. Simple but not all data:

```js
page.on('request', async function (request) {
    // HTTP method
    console.log(request.method());
    // Request target, usually a URL
    console.log(request.url());
    // The HTTP version
    // N/A
    // HTTP headers
    console.log(request.headers());
    // Body
    console.log(request.postData());
});
```

2. Not so simple as previous, but with full data:

```js
await page.tracing.start({ path: 'trace.json', categories: ['netlog'] });
await page.goto('http://example.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
const tracing = JSON.parse(await page.tracing.stop());
// Some filtering
const res = await tracing.traceEvents.filter(te => te.name.toLowerCase().includes(`${some_desired_name}`));
```

- You can include different tracing categories. In this example '*netlog*' category is used only. You can read a short intro to tracing in this [article](https://slack.engineering/chrome-tracing-for-fun-and-profit/#:%7E:text=Open%20chrome%3A%2F%2Ftracing%20in,well%20as%20the%20renderer%20process.).
- You should collect data by yourself from this tracing.
- It uses [Tracing](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v9.0.0&show=api-class-tracing) class.
- This code creates tracing file ('*trace.json*') which can be inspected in DevTools.